# Backbone in Rails with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I'm using gem "rails-backbone" and trying to do this example, which is made with javascript.

What should I do here to make it work? Because most examples I find to learn is made with javascript and I need them to work in my RoR app. Trying to figure this out so long but have no idea how... I need some help to start using backbone for real. Here are my files. What should I change/add here exactly? I think I won't understand partial, need a full explanation. Thx

app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

app/assets/javascripts/backbone/models/welcome.js

```
var Rectangle = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

app/assets/javascripts/backbone/views/welcome/inde_view.js

```
var RectangleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: 'rectange',
    render: function() {
        this.setDimensions();
        this.setPosition();
        return this;
    },
    setDimensions: function() {
                this.$el.css({
                width: this.model.get('width') + 'px',
                height: this.model.get('height') + 'px'
            });
            },

    setPosition: function() {
             var position = this.model.get('position');
             this.$el.css({
                left: position.x,
            top: position.y
             });
             }

});
var myRectangle = new Rectangle({
    width: 100,
    height: 60,
    position: {
        x: 300,
    y: 150
    }
});

var myView = new RectangleView({model: myRectangle});

$('div#canvas').append(myView.render().el);
```

Comment: Looks like `el` is not being set anywhere. IE. something like: `new RectangeView({mode: myRectangle, el: $('#some_div')});`. Or, create the `el` in an initialize function in the view.

Comment: Hi/ Good questions :) to make css isnt a problem, but this example is from tutorial and most tutorials are like this. I cant learn any of them becouse i dont know how to use them in Rails. Lets say here is one file, how to split all this in Rails? Where to put the script of Bacbone meanning that i have installed gem "rails-backbone"?